# Error while storing file in JSON to send to mobile app

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to store array in JSON, however, the JSON file is taking spaces or spaces character and the code is giving me the error in JSON validator.

Following is my code:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/init.php';
require CLASS_PATH.'user.php';
require CLASS_PATH.'news.php';
require CLASS_PATH.'podcast.php';

$user = new User();

$podcast = new Podcast();

$news = new News();

$userList = $user->getAllUserName();

foreach ($userList as $users) {

$fullname = $users->full_name; 

$profile = $users->image;

$podcastList = $podcast->getUserPodcast($fullname);
$output = [];
if (!empty($podcastList)) {
    $output[] = array(
    'name'  => $fullname,
    'profile'   => $profile,
    'podcast' => $podcastList
);
}

}

$newsList = $news->getAllNews();

if ($newsList) {
$data = array();
foreach ($newsList as $value) {
    $data = array(
        'id'=>$value->id,
        'title'=>$value->title,
        'story'=>html_entity_decode($value->story),
        'image'=>$value->image,
        'added_date'=>$value->added_date,
        'news_category'=>$value->news_category,
        'author'=>$value->author
    );
}
}

$json = array(
'news'  => $data,
'podcast'   => $output
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

And whenever I run this file it gives me the following error:

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>   \u0938\ u0930\ u091
>   ^
>   Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

How do I fix this?

Comment: `\u0938` is a `स` ...which means you are outputting something very else.

Comment: Yes! I am outputting Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible answer might be:

to send `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`